# Difference between ListenableFuture-style stub and async stub in grpc java

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

what is the difference ListenableFuture-style stub and Async stub in gRPC java implementation?

Which one to use for async communication?

```
public static MyServiceStub newStub(io.grpc.Channel channel) {
    io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub.StubFactory<MyServiceStub> factory =
      new io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub.StubFactory<MyServiceStub>() {
        @java.lang.Override
        public MyServiceStub newStub(io.grpc.Channel channel, io.grpc.CallOptions callOptions) {
          return new MyServiceStub(channel, callOptions);
        }
      };
    return MyServiceStub.newStub(factory, channel);
  }


public static MyServiceBlockingStub newBlockingStub(
      io.grpc.Channel channel) {
    io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub.StubFactory<MyServiceBlockingStub> factory =
      new io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub.StubFactory<MyServiceBlockingStub>() {
        @java.lang.Override
        public MyServiceBlockingStub newStub(io.grpc.Channel channel, io.grpc.CallOptions callOptions) {
          return new MyServiceBlockingStub(channel, callOptions);
        }
      };
    return MyServiceBlockingStub.newStub(factory, channel);
  }




public static MyServiceFutureStub newFutureStub(
      io.grpc.Channel channel) {
    io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub.StubFactory<MyServiceFutureStub> factory =
      new io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub.StubFactory<MyServiceFutureStub>() {
        @java.lang.Override
        public MyServiceFutureStub newStub(io.grpc.Channel channel, io.grpc.CallOptions callOptions) {
          return new MyServiceFutureStub(channel, callOptions);
        }
      };
    return MyServiceFutureStub.newStub(factory, channel);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync vs async stubs has no impact on the *communication*. The stubs in grpc-java are a small shim on top of the Channel API and the stubs differ in that they are different APIs. Simply choose the stub type that most closely matches how you want to receive responses. If you like the async API, use the async API; if you like the Future API, use the Future API; if you like sync, use sync.